# Using array_push() Help

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, push

I have a variable holding an array of errors

```
$errors = array();
```

I also have an if statement that returns whether or not a username has been entered in an input.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
        echo array_push($errors, 'You did not submit a username' );
    }
}
```

I'm using array_push() to add an error message at the end of it. I'm using a for each loop to retrieve the values of all the error fields. although I keep getting the number of array values as well as just the intended string.... For instance it will echo out "1 You did not submit a username"

```
foreach($errors as $e) {
    echo $e;
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

is there anyway to retrieve just the required string?

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra echo:

```
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {
    /* here */ array_push($errors, 'You did not submit a username' );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `echo` from `echo array_push($errors, 'You did not submit a username' );`. It's not needed, and that is what's echoing the 1 in your result.